# How to convert string to time format in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime-format

I fetch data from SQLite db like "16:00" as string now I want to convert to time format and add 10 minutes. How can I do this in react js?

Comment: You should mention what you have tried, look at something like this - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ReactJS task :)

You can work with dates using JavaScript, but the API
is not "very good" (IMHO).

I can suggest [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) as I usually use it, but there are many different libs to work with Date/Time easily.

You can add Moment to your app:

```
npm install moment --save   # npm
yarn add moment             # Yarn
```

Moment API example:

```
const date = moment.utc()
                   .hour(16)   // numbers from 0 to 23
                   .minute(0); // numbers from 0 to 59
const plus10Min = date.add(10, 'm')
```

[Here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) you can find very nice documentation with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know the year, month and day - this is what you can do

```
var hour = row[<index of the column>].split(":")[0];
var minute = row[<index of the column>].split(":")[1];

var updatedMinute = parseInt(minute) + 10;

var date = new Date(year,month,day, hour, updatedMinute+'');
```